# How to center canvas javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to center the canvas in the page.  The canvas's code is in a javascript file.  Here's the html for the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Game Tut</title>
   </head>
   <body>

       <script src="game.js"></script>
   </body>
 </html>
```

I've tried something like this in the javascript file.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
canvas.tabindex = 0;
canvas.style = "position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; border:2px solid blue"
document.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

For some reason the blue border or the positioning don't seem to show up in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

the code below made the canvas center

```
canvas.style = "position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; margin: auto; border:2px solid blue";
```

By the way

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
```

I posted your code but chrome showed the **'doKeyDown'** function is undefined so maybe you need to fix this error then your canvas will show correctly.

[Error showed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpGLO.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByName("canvas")[0];
var style = canvas.style;
style.marginLeft = "auto";
style.marginRight = "auto";
var parentStyle = canvas.parentElement.style;
parentStyle.textAlign = "center";
parentStyle.width = "100%";
```

OR

```
canvas.style = "position:absolute; left: 50%; width: 400px; margin-left: -200px;";
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
canvas.tabindex = 0;
canvas.setAttribute('style', "position: absolute;  left: 50%;margin-left:-400px; top: 50%;margin-top:-300px; border:2px solid blue");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
document.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
```